# Can't calculate numbers in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I want to calculate some metrics in jenkins pipeline script like this:

```
a=$(($numObj/1000))
```

And I always get this error:

```
 arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "/1000"
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Your question will eventually boil down to groovy string interpolation. To debug it, try starting with `sh ''' echo 'a=$(($numObj/1000)) ' '''`

Comment: If you want the number as an integer or float you can just do `a = numObj / 1000` if you want it as a string you would do `a = "${ numObj / 1000 }"`